# My React Frontend project runs correctly at the hosting server but does not appear in the browser

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, vite, vpn, web-frontend

i devloped Frontend with react in (windows as os) ,then i passed to production stpes were i allocate a virtual machine (ubuntu as os) at hosting serveur and move my project builg it the run it as u see in the picture [project runing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rlmas.png), the run render to me the ip adress and the port where could i access to my site but when i try to access using VPN my site dosnt appear such as i can ping the virtual machine [my site dosn't appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pgk3.png), i contact hosting service about the port if they are opened , they say are opened see pic [port 5173 is open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqtCo.png)

where is the prbleme ?? in the port or something else

Comment: Is that port open on that machine?

Comment: yes i checked port in vm it is opened

Comment: is that port open in ubuntu? sudo ufw allow 5173

Comment: yes this port is allowed i typed ur command and nothing change , hosting service has physical firwall is it possible the physical firewall prevent me to access ?